# Outlook/SharePoint calendar sync 'error' & HTTPS configurations

Tags: outlook

I have a problem so I explain my situation :

I have this Web Applications : 
`https://sharepoint.mycompany.be`  ==> SharePoint web site, before the name was mycompany-srv-012, this name was use for the first time when I created the web site. But now this site is public, so we had configure this URL public site by default in AAM.

My Alternate Access Mapping look like this for sharepoint.mycompany.be :

Internal URL -------------------- Zone ---------- Public URL for Zone

```
https://sharepoint.mycompany.be -- **Par défaut** ---- https://sharepoint.mycompany.be 

http://mycompany------------------- Intranet ------ http://mycompany

http://sharepoint.mycompany.be ---- Internet ------ http://sharepoint.mycompany.be 

http://mycompany-srv-012 ---------- Personnalisée - http://mycompany-srv-012 (last default)
```

Before explain my problems, Note, I create a new AAM for https (**`https://sharepoint.mycompany.be`**) **and** I secure my SharePoint. I secure my SharePoint by creating a Rule with IIS (Internet information Services) by using URL Rewrite.
With this tutorial: 
http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/

So, I have strange problems :

1) `http://mycompany-srv-012 & http://sharepoint` redirect to `HTTPS://mycompany-srv-012 & HTTPS://sharepoint` BUT for example when I try to create a new item in a list, I have the message :

> The list does not exist.
>
> The selected page contains a list that does not exist. It may have
>   been deleted by another user.

But I can see the list.. And I have no problems when I extract document or convert a document..

2) My second problem is with `http://sharepoint.mycompany.be`, I have no problems with list. But with Outlook, when I sync my calendar and task, the first time the calendar syncs, but after I have this message:

**Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80070005): 'You do not have permission to view this SharePoint List (Develop - Calendar). Contact the SharePoint site administrator. HTTP 303.'**

**This is the main problem of my SharePoint.**

So, I don't know if I have a problem with my AAMs or with my redirection.

So if anyone can help me :)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance